# error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints (A53) - gcc 9.3.1

Tags: gcc, arm, constraints, inline-assembly, gcc9

This is code to read 64bit address space.  Issue showed up with gcc 9.3.1, did not have issue with earlier version of gcc

```
    static inline void write_to_64bit_address(uint64_t address, 
    uint32_t data) {
    uint32_t address_upper = (uint32_t)(address >> 32);
    uint32_t address_lower = (uint32_t)(address);
    uint32_t smc_code = SMC_LONG_ADDRESS_WRITE_SINGLE;
    asm volatile("mov r0, %[smc_code]\n"
                 "mov r1, %[addr_upper]\n"
                 "mov r2, %[addr_lower]\n"
                 "mov r3, %[data_all]\n"
                 "mov r4, %[smc_zero]\n"
                 "mov r5, %[smc_zero]\n"
                 "mov r6, %[smc_zero]\n"
                 "smc #0\n"
                 :
                 : [smc_code] "r"(smc_code),
                   [addr_upper] "r"(address_upper),
                   [addr_lower] "r"(address_lower),
                   [data_all] "r"(data),
                   [smc_zero] "g"(SMC_ZERO)
                 : "r0","r1","r2","r3","r4", "r5", "r6");
}
```

I don't understand this assembly as well and learning.  Can someone help.

Comment: Seems to work here: https://godbolt.org/z/8K4rqYKTe.  How  are `SMC_LONG_ADDRESS_WRITE_SINGLE` and `SMC_ZERO` defined?  What compiler options are you using?  Can you make a [mcve], in case this depends on the function you're inlining into?

Comment: Yeah, even works with `-O0 -fPIC` on Godbolt, with/without `-mcpu=cortex-a53`.  (GCC sometimes doesn't have as many free registers in un-optimized code, or doesn't CSE equal operands into the same input register, although this is more often a problem for addressing modes for different `"m"` operands).  Are you using `-ffixed-r7` or anything that ties up another register pemanently?  Or `register uint32_t foo asm("r0")` or something that could conflict with a clobber?

Comment: Also, normally write constraints to get the compiler to put stuff in the right register in the first place (using register-asm local vars to force it to pick that for `"r"`).  Don't use `mov` as the first or last instruction of the asm template.  Especially not reading `smc_zero` 3 times if it might be a memory operand instead of a small immediate.  Anyway, that will let you tell the compiler which input values are modified or not by the `smc #0` instruction, so it doesn't have to reload them if it wants them after.